# How to retrieve more posts from a custom post type that are in the same category as the current post

Tags: categories, post-type

The site I'm working on is using a plugin IssueM that created a custom post type called article, and has a custom taxonomy called **issuem_issue_categories** that has categories such as boat-profile, product-reviews, technique, etc. There are then posts within the article post type of course, and they are in those categories.

Further down the page I am trying to show more posts that are in that same category, but with the query below, I am only getting back 'regular' posts from the built in wordpress post type. I have tried a bunch of different queries, but just cannot get it to return what I need. I know I only have the_title() in there now, but I assume I will be able to get the_post_thumbnail, and the_excerpt too once I actually get it working..

```
<?php
$args = array (
    array(
        'post_type' => 'article',

        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'issuem_issue_categories',
                'field'    => 'slug',
            )
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        the_title();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();

}
?>
```

Comment: I think you are missing arguments in your tax query (https://www.billerickson.net/code/wp_query-arguments/) - There should be `terms` and `include_children`. It would be really help full if you could include some data from database. That way you can figure out how to call specific fields.

Comment: @Fresz so, I added the include children, switched the field to ID, and for the terms I used array(5) and that actually does what I want, but I don’t want to have it hard coded to one ID, and I can’t seem to figure out a way to get, and use the current post category that I’m on as the terms, since I only want to show posts in the same category for the page being viewed, is there a way to do this? Also, I’m gonna need to show the category name, and excerpt (already got the thumb, and title) and while I haven’t tried the excerpt yet, neither get_the_category() or the_category() were working.

Comment: You need to get term id of current displayed post then use that term id to build query for posts in that term.

Comment: Use the get_the_terms to get term id or slug of current post.

Comment: @RyanHilton I think you started a bit wrong (I should have spotted it at the start). So, first you need to get current post ID, then from that ID you can get the correct term (category - get_the_terms or get_terms). Once you have term slug/id/name you can amend your query to display posts from term that is also in the main post. Let me know if that is the answer.

Comment: @Fresz after trying a bunch of different get named functions, get_terms, etc, nothing seemed to work, then I found a function called wp_get_post_terms() that somebody had posted on a css tricks forum looking for help and it's the only thing that was returning the current page's category. There may be a better way, but I ended up using this:

`$term_list = wp_get_post_terms (
 $post->ID, 'issuem_issue_categories',
 array( 'fields' => 'ids')
);`

I then used `'terms' => $term_list` in the tax query.

Comment: @Fresz and then to print it to the page (this code was on the same css tricks post thankfully)

`$link_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'issuem_issue_categories' );
         foreach ( $link_terms as $term ) {
          $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'issuem_issue_categories' );
          echo '<a href="' . esc_url($term_link) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
         }`

Also, why does my code not show formatted properly in the comments like it does in my original post? I used the backticks..

Thank you for responding, and for the link.

Comment: @Fresz something else I thought that was funny was that all I needed on the tax_query was:

`array(
'taxonomy'  => 'issuem_issue_categories', 
'terms' => $term_list`

I didn't even need these:

`'field'             => 'ID',
'include_children'  => true,
'operator'          => 'IN'`

Comment: Can you update ur code or post an answer. I am glad u found the solution